# New button for Foreign Key fields in Dynamic Data

Tags: asp.net, dynamic-data

In a scaffolded page in ASP.NET Dynamic Data, if the entity has a foreign key field, and the value you seek is not in the the primary key table, i.e. is not in the drop-down, you have to abandon your edits to the entity, add the sought foreign key value to its table, and return to your original entity.

How could I go about adding a 'New' link/button to the foreign key field template, that would open a new window (make a Panel visible) where you can add the sought value, and then refresh the drop-down?

Comment: I know it does not answer your question, but personally, it sounds like you need an input wizard and not rely completely on DyDa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean like in the django admin ui ;).
I'm currently trying to implement that feature, i'll post the code here if I get it to work.

EDIT:

Ok, I got that to work, complete django style... It's kinda long to explain but simple in fact.

**Files to create:**

A admin_popup.master to have a nice popup page (copy the admin.master without the header).

A popup_Insert.aspx with admin_popup.master as master. (copy the Insert.aspx)

**Modifications**

To your admin.master.cs:
add this:

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnInit(e);

    System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, Page.GetType(), "refresh_fks", @"
    var fk_dropdown_id;
    function refresh() {
        __doPostBack(fk_dropdown_id,'refresh');
    };", true);
}
```

In your admin_popup.master, add these attributes to the body tag (it's used to resize the poup)

```
<body style="display: inline-block;" onload="javascript:resizeWindow();">
```

In your admin_popup.master.cs

```
protected override void  OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnInit(e);

    System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, Page.GetType(), "refresh_fks", @"
    var fk_dropdown_id;
    function refresh() {
        __doPostBack(fk_dropdown_id,'refresh');
    };", true);

    System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, Page.GetType(), "resize_window", @"function resizeWindow() {
        window.resizeTo(document.body.clientWidth + 20, document.body.clientHeight + 40);
        window.innerHeight = document.body.clientHeight + 5;
        window.innerWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
    }", true);

    System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, Page.GetType(), "update_parent", @"function updateParent() {
        window.opener.refresh();
    }", true);        
}
```

In popup_Insert.aspx.cs, replace these two functions:

```
protected void DetailsView1_ItemCommand(object sender, DetailsViewCommandEventArgs e) {
    if (e.CommandName == DataControlCommands.CancelCommandName)
        System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "Close_Window", "self.close();", true); 
}

protected void DetailsView1_ItemInserted(object sender, DetailsViewInsertedEventArgs e) {
    if (e.Exception == null || e.ExceptionHandled) {
        System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "Close_Window", "window.opener.refresh(); self.close();", true); 
    }
}
```

In ForeignKey_Edit.ascx, add a LinkButton (ID=LinkButton1) and in ForeignKey_Edit.ascx.cs, replace that function

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (DropDownList1.Items.Count == 0)
    {
        if (!Column.IsRequired) {
            DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem("[Not Set]", ""));
        }

        PopulateListControl(DropDownList1);
        LinkButton1.OnClientClick = @"javascript:fk_dropdown_id = '{0}';window.open('{1}', '{2}', config='{3}');return false;".FormatWith(
            DropDownList1.ClientID,
            ForeignKeyColumn.ParentTable.GetPopupActionPath(PageAction.Insert),
            "fk_popup_" + ForeignKeyColumn.ParentTable.Name, "height=400,width=600,toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no");
    }
    if (Request["__eventargument"] == "refresh")
    {
        DropDownList1.Items.Clear();
        if (!Column.IsRequired)
        {
            DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem("[Not Set]", ""));
        }

        PopulateListControl(DropDownList1);
        DropDownList1.SelectedIndex = DropDownList1.Items.Count - 1;
    }
}
```

And finally the two extentions functions I use (put it where you want to):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Web.DynamicData;
using System.Web.UI;

public static class Utils
{
    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    public static string FormatWith(this string s, params object[] args)
    {
        return string.Format(s, args);
    }

    public static string GetPopupActionPath(this MetaTable mt, string action)
    {
        return new Control().ResolveUrl("~/{0}/popup_{1}.aspx".FormatWith(mt.Name, action));
    }
}
```

In your global.asax, register the new route by changing that line:

```
Constraints = new RouteValueDictionary(new { action = "List|Details|Edit|Insert|popup_Insert" }),
```

Ok I hope i didn't forgot anything... It certainly could be improved, but it works.
Ok I hope some people will fint that useful, it makes ASP.NET Dynamic Data a lot more better ;). I'm goind to take a look at many-to-many relationships now.

Answer (score 2):

ATTN: VB.net USERS

If you have been like me and fuming at the mouth over how convoluted and a mess Dynamic Data is, this is for YOU!  It has taken me over 100 hours just to figure out the basics of DD (even though I am very versed in other database programming techiniques).

Guillaume's solution is much easier than Naughton's for us.  After 15+ hours of trying to translate Naughton's I tried to translate Guillaume's code which took me only 2 hours to get to work. Here it is in the same order.  (Note: cs extensions of course translate to vb extensions)

1. Ignore the admin.master.cs directions.
2. Do the admin_popup.master code.  If you are still in VS 2008 or older you'll get a CSS error on the inline block quote.  Ignore the error.
3. MASTER FILE OnInit Sub:

   ```
   Protected Overrides Sub OnInit(ByVal e As EventArgs)
   MyBase.OnInit(e)
   System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, Page.GetType, "refresh_fks", "     var fk_dropdown_id;     function refresh() {         __doPostBack(fk_dropdown_id,'refresh');     };", True)
   System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, Page.GetType, "resize_window", "function resizeWindow() {         window.resizeTo(document.body.clientWidth + 120, document.body.clientHeight + 120);         window.innerHeight = document.body.clientHeight + 5;         window.innerWidth = document.body.clientWidth;     }", True)
   System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, Page.GetType, "update_parent", "function updateParent() {        window.opener.location.reload(true);     }", True)
   ```

   End Sub
4. Replace the events in (popup_Insert.aspx.vb) under your custom pages with this:

   ```
   Protected Sub DetailsView1_ItemCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DetailsViewCommandEventArgs)
   If e.CommandName = DataControlCommands.CancelCommandName Then
       System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me, Me.GetType, "Close_Window", "self.close();", True)
   End If
   ```

   End Sub
   Protected Sub DetailsView1_ItemInserted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DetailsViewInsertedEventArgs)
       If e.Exception Is Nothing OrElse e.ExceptionHandled Then
           System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me, Me.GetType, "Close_Window", "window.opener.location.reload(true); self.close();", True)
       End If
   End Sub
5. Create a custom FieldTemplate off the ForeignKey_Edit and name it ForeignLinkKey_Edit.ascx.  After the dropdownlist1 control, add two spaces ( ) and then create the asp:LinkButton as he stated.  Put text like "Add __" or something like that.  Replace the Page Load function with this:

   ```
   Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
   If DropDownList1.Items.Count = 0 Then
       If Not Column.IsRequired Then
           DropDownList1.Items.Add(New ListItem("[Not Set]", ""))
       End If
       PopulateListControl(DropDownList1)

       LinkButton1.OnClientClick = "javascript:fk_dropdown_id = '" & DropDownList1.ClientID & _
   ```

   "';window.open('" & ForeignKeyColumn.ParentTable.GetActionPath("Insert").Replace("Insert.aspx", "popup_Insert.aspx") & _
   "', '" & "fk_popup_" & ForeignKeyColumn.ParentTable.Name & "', config='" & _
   "height=400,width=400,toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no" & "');return false;"
       End If
       If Request("__eventargument") = "refresh" Then
           DropDownList1.Items.Clear()
           If Not Column.IsRequired Then
               DropDownList1.Items.Add(New ListItem("[Not Set]", ""))
           End If
           PopulateListControl(DropDownList1)
           DropDownList1.SelectedIndex = DropDownList1.Items.Count - 1
       End If
   End Sub
6. Ignore the extensions functions.
7. Do the updated routing suggested.  Note: If you are using custom routes, you'll have to tinker with it until the routing is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Or I have just created two server controls and a blog post here: 
[A Popup Insert control for Dynamic Data](http://csharpbits.notaclue.net/2009/12/popup-insert-control-for-dynamic-data.html) that does pretty much the same but encapsulates the popup functionlity in the server controls passing a value bak from the popup windows to main windows and popup button.

Answer (score 1):

Any new features in Dynamic Data in the VS2010 RC? Will we still have to resort to hacks such as these for simple Master-Details in Dynamic Data under this RC?

Looking forward to some blog posts on DD under VS2010 RC...

Comment: I'll try and get some out this week.